# how to forward a email as an attachment by outlook addin web

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is this possible to send a email by outlook add-in web?

Forwarding an email as an attachment by C# outlook add-in is easy to do, but it's not working for outlook client of the mac OS. so I have to try use [new office feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator). But I didn't find a way to send email in development documents

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
})();`
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Office JavaScript API` doesn't provide anything for that (any property or method out of the box). Office web add-ins work under the context of currently opened/selected item in Outlook only. Only users can send or forward emails in Outlook or any software from the backend-side (Exchange) in case of web add-ins. As a possible workaround, consider using the `Graph API` or `EWS` for sending emails, see [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) for more information.

Note, you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Eugene sending mail is not supported via Outlook Web Add-ins and you can consider using Graph API or REST APIs. For adding an item as attachment you can use [addItemAttachmentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-1.12&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-messagecompose-additemattachmentasync-member(1)) API  .